# Looking for how to add a new member

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine

Where can I now find the admin members page in the appengine.google.com console?

It looks like Google changed to a new interface in the appengine console. I'm trying to add a new member but I can't find where to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the new [Google Cloud Identity & Access Management (IAM)](https://cloud.google.com/iam/) you are able to have more fine-grained control over the access permissions to your Google Cloud project resources.

Managing members of your project are now done directly in the [IAM Dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/iam/). For more information on the processes, you can take a look at the guides provided in our [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access#granting_access_to_team_members).